# "dotnet-ef does not exist" in .net core heroku application

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, heroku, entity-framework-core

I am using jincod's [Heroku .NET Core Buildpack](https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack) to deploy my Core 3.1 MVC application to heroku.

Currently i am trying to apply EF migrations to postgre DB (using Npgsql) by executing command on publish:

```
  <Target Name="PrePublishTarget" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef" />
    <Exec Command="dotnet ef database update" />
  </Target>
```

Build fails with these messages:

```
  You can invoke the tool using the following command: dotnet-ef
  Tool 'dotnet-ef' (version '3.1.3') was successfully installed.
  Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
  Possible reasons for this include:
    * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
    * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
    * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
/tmp/build_35cf57c00fbf62634ac8d644c6e8f4f7/BugTracker.csproj(38,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet ef database update" exited with code 1.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile ASP.NET Core app.
 !     Push failed
```

I explicitly install dotnet-ef, but for some reason it cannot find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add "dotnet-tools.json". More info here https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack/pull/104